# Swap NA's with values whilst preserving original value order

Tags: r, dataframe

consider an ordered dataframe with a column that consists of values and NA's like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:6), value=c(NA,NA,23,45,12,76))
```

I would like to shift the position of the NA's to the first two rows of the data frame, whilst maintaining the order of the values as so:

```
df$new_value <- c(23,45,12,76,NA,NA)
```

Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `order` on the `NA` elements

```
df$new_value <- df$value[order(is.na(df$value))]
df$new_value
#[1] 23 45 12 76 NA NA
```

---

By doing `is.na`, it returns a logical vector

```
 is.na(df$value)
 #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

applying `order` on it returns

```
order(is.na(df$value))
#[1] 3 4 5 6 1 2
```

because `FALSE` is considered first before `TRUE` alphabetically.  The `order` values are the initial position index of the vector.  This can be understand more easily with

```
sort(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), index.return = TRUE)
#$x
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

#$ix
#[1] 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea which will work **only If your NAs are at the very end of your dataframe**, is to use the `lead` function from `dplyr` in order to shift your data n positions forward. So for your case, it would be,

```
dplyr::lead(df$value, sum(is.na(df$value)))
#[1] 23 45 12 76 NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks! The dplyr solution is better for my needs, however, your's doesn't seem to work with `group_by`, e.g.: `df <- data.frame(fact=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), id=rep(1:6), value=c(NA,44,23,NA,NA,76))`  `df <- df %>% group_by(fact) %>% mutate(newvar = dplyr::lead(df$value, sum(is.na(df$value))))`

Answer (score 1):

Without being clever some elementary techniques can also be applied:

```
df$new_value <- c(df[!is.na(df$value), "value"], df[is.na(df$value), "value"])

  id value new_value
1  1    NA        23
2  2    NA        45
3  3    23        12
4  4    45        76
5  5    12        NA
6  6    76        NA
```